# The client rendering is called after Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices SSR

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-2.0, server-side-rendering

I'm using React+Redux SPA template for creating ASP.NET Core SPA in VS2017 and as I understand SSR philosophy a server fully renders a page content and a client should just display that.
I see in the browser network tab that the server sends initialReduxState and the rendered content, but if I put a breakpoint on the client in any render functions I see that is called. I don't understand why the client runs a render cycle again and what is reason of SSR if we rewrite that content on the client anyway.
I did a small experiment and deleted
html: renderToString(app)
from

```
params.domainTasks.then(() => {
        resolve({
            html: '',
            globals: { initialReduxState: store.getState() }
        });
    }, reject);
```

and nothing is changed. The client successfully displays the page content without SSR content.
So, how to prevent the client render cycle after SSR?

Answer (score 0):

SSR is mainly used for `SEO and performance purposes`. You can read more about it in [this article](https://medium.com/walmartlabs/the-benefits-of-server-side-rendering-over-client-side-rendering-5d07ff2cefe8).

The client side does not actually re-paints the whole page. React expects that the rendered content is identical between the server and the client and so, it tries to patch up the difference between client and server.

Quoting from official [website](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html):

> ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element) renders a React element to its initial HTML. React will return an HTML string. You can use this method to generate HTML on the server and send the markup down on the initial request for faster page loads and to allow search engines to crawl your pages for SEO purposes.
>
> If you call ReactDOM.hydrate() on a node that already has this server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load experience.

So, page is not actually re-painted. Client is reusing the HTML send by server for faster performance.